# Does there exists $F:\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ such that $F^{\prime} (z) = f(z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function such that $\int_{\gamma} f = 0$ for every simple closed curve $\gamma$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. Then which of the following is /are true?

1. $f$ has removal singularity at $0$.
2. $f$  cannot have essential singularity at $0$.
3. There exists a holomorphic function $F:\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}  \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ such that $F^{\prime} (z) = f(z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$.
4. There exist a holomorphic function $F: \mathbb{C} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ such that $F^{\prime} (z)= f(z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

I think only option 3 is true by Morera's theorem. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

For 2) consider $\frac 1  {z^{2}}e^{1/z}$. Being a derivative, its integral over any closed curve is $0$.

For 1) and 4) use $f(z)=\frac 1 {z^{2}}$: If 4) holds then $f$ would be analytic on $\mathbb C$!.

3. is true: Fix any $z_0$ and define $F(z)=\int_{\gamma} f(\zeta)d\zeta$ where $\gamma$ is any path from $z_0$ to $z$ in $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$. $F$ is well-defined and $F'(z)=f(z)$ for all $z$.

Comment: $\frac 1  {z^{2}}e^{1/z}$ has  a pole  of order  $2$.I am  not getting  why  is   $\frac 1  {z^{2}}e^{1/z}$  have essential singularity at $0$? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Expand $e^{1/z}$ using the power series for $e^{z}$. You will get infinitely many non-zero terms in negative powers of $z$ for $\frac 1 {z^{2}}e^{1/z}$. This implies that there is an essential singularity at $0$. @jasmine

Comment: okay  @geetha290krm  You mean the principal part has an infinite number of terms .Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, that is right. @jasmine